# django post_save causing IntegrityError - duplicate entry

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-signals

I need help to fix the issue `IntegrityError at /admin/gp/schprograms/add/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '65' for key 'PRIMARY'")`
 I am trying to insert a row into a table `SchProgramForStates` (whenever new entry gets added into a model `SchPrograms`) with two columns `state_id` (taking it from django session) and `program_id` trying to take it from `SchPrograms` model class . It works fine when I only save `SchProgram` table   so I feel problem is with the below code. Please help me to fix this.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=SchPrograms, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
def my_callback(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    state_id = state_id_filter #its a global variable 
    if created and not kwargs.get('raw', False):
        pfst_id = SchProgramForStates.objects.create(program_id=instance.program_id, state_id=state_id)
        pfst_id.save(force_insert=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if created and not kwargs.get('raw', False):
    try:
        pfst_id = SchProgramForStates.objects.create(program_id=instance.program_id, state_id=state_id)
    except:
        pass
```

Try with a try block and see or you can use a get or create method

```
if created and not kwargs.get('raw', False):
        pfst_id = SchProgramForStates.objects.get_or_create(program_id=instance.program_id, state_id=state_id)
```

Comment: It does not gives any error and says that `sch programs` was added successfully but it does not seem to get inserted into the database. and also I have added this line of code `pfst_id.save(force_insert=True)` into the try.